# Le verbe « être » doit-il avoir un complément ?

Tags: grammaire, compléments

En lisant le livre de la Génèse, j'ai remarqué ces utilisations du verbe être :

> Dieu dit: "Que la lumière soit !" Et la lumière fut. ([Source](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/f/ft/ft0101.htm).)

Dans chaque cas, il n'y a pas de [complément](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compl%C3%A9ment_(grammaire)) au verbe être. J'ai toujours cru qu'il fallait en général en mettre un. Avais-je tort ? Dans ce cas, quand peut-on omettre un complément après le verbe être ? Sinon, pourquoi n'y en a-t-il pas ici ?

Je sais qu'en anglais, on peut utiliser « to be » sans explicitement donner un complément si on a un complément implicite. (Par exemple: "Are you in university?" "I *am* [in university].") J'imagine que le français est similaire, mais dans ces cas, il n'y a pas tels compléments implicite.

Comment: Note: I wrote this in French since I figured I needed more practice _writing_ in French. (I'm generally somewhat more focused on learning grammar rules and making sure I can read.) Feel free to correct any errors that may have appeared.

Comment: Cet exemple est très particulier. C'est un choix stylistique très habille, notamment parce qu'il s'agit là d'un emploi entièrement inhabituel. Je ne pense qu'à un seul autre exemple : « Je pense, donc je suis. » Encore une fois, très fondationnel.

Comment: « Être ou ne pas être, telle est la question […] »

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cette utilisation du verbe être est très rare et dans ce cas, le verbe être signifie exister, comme c'est aussi le cas dans les commentaires de Stéphane Gimenez et Édouard:

> Je pense donc je suis.
>
> Être ou ne pas être, telle est la question…

Dans la vie courante, être n'est jamais utilisé seul :

> — Tu es à l'université ?
> — J'y suis.

L'hypothétique réponse « Je suis » ne serais pas comprise en français en entraînerait probablement la question suivante: « Tu es quoi ? ».

Comment: This makes sense, and thanks for the last bit. (I ended up thinking about the question in a "broader" sense before making that edit -- in terms of whether any of the languages I know _ever_ permit such usage of the "to be" words -- and so must have somehow missed the fact that I'd normally _not_ want to answer such questions with  « Je suis »).